# Transfer DNS zones from master to slave (MS DNS to BIND9)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a problem with DNS servers. My master dns server runs on Microsoft DNS server and now I want to start slave DNS server on Linux Bind9. The problems is that master MS DNS server can't validate slave DNS server (bind9) and can't resolve FQDN. Maybe, I missed something... firewall, dns configuration and network looks like ok.

And the second question is: How I can make full transfer of dns zones to slave dns server? from MS DNS to BIND9

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Bryan

Answer (score 2):

On your Windows DNS server, select the properties of the domain name and on the Zone Transfers tab, check the Allow Zone Transfers box.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. I have checked the "Allow Zone Transfers" and choose "Only to servers listed in the Name Servers tab" On the Name Servers tab there are 4 name servers, the new slave name server also included in that list, but problems still alive. Moreover, on same menu, on Name Server tab when I choose my new name server, the MS DNS server can't validate it, it shows me "A timeout occurred during validation." Maybe, something wrong with Linux dns? Thank You.

Comment: Make sure port 53/udp and 53/tcp is open between the Windows box and the Linux box.